# Calculating appropriate image size in Android

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm currently using the code here to decode images in Android:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

I'm using a MinSize of 1024 for decode, this works perfectly fine on higher end devices like the Galaxy S4, Galaxy Note 3, Galaxy Tab 3, Xperia Z and HTC One M8.

The only issue I'm having is this is crashing the app in some weaker phones such as the Galaxy S2 and Nexus One.

I'm attempting to downsample the image to a Min width and height of 1024 pixels and on the Galaxy S2 and Nexus One it's throwing an `OutOfMemoryError` when I attempt to load the file.

Is there a way I can calculate an appropriate image size that won't crash the Galaxy S2 and Nexus One but still retain appropriate quality on higher end devices like the Galaxy S4?

The stack trace for the crash on the Galaxy S2 is below:

```
06-10 21:17:18.345 I/dalvikvm-heap( 5973): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 5992720-byte allocation
06-10 21:17:18.380 D/dalvikvm( 5973): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed <1K, 17% free 36845K/43911K, paused 34ms, total 34ms
06-10 21:17:18.380 E/dalvikvm-heap( 5973): Out of memory on a 5992720-byte allocation.
06-10 21:17:18.380 I/dalvikvm( 5973): "Thread-3353" prio=5 tid=26 RUNNABLE
06-10 21:17:18.380 I/dalvikvm( 5973):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x420cf690 self=0x54c821a0
06-10 21:17:18.380 I/dalvikvm( 5973):   | sysTid=6099 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1422403056
06-10 21:17:18.380 I/dalvikvm( 5973):   | schedstat=( 1566617822 87113594 202 ) utm=152 stm=4 core=0
06-10 21:17:18.385 I/dalvikvm( 5973):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
06-10 21:17:18.385 I/dalvikvm( 5973):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:640)
06-10 21:17:18.390 I/dalvikvm( 5973):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:575)
06-10 21:17:18.390 I/dalvikvm( 5973):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:501)
06-10 21:17:18.390 I/dalvikvm( 5973):   at com.aura.app.fragments.CameraFragment$AuraCameraHost.saveImage(CameraFragment.java:675)
06-10 21:17:18.390 I/dalvikvm( 5973):   at com.commonsware.cwac.camera.ImageCleanupTask.run(ImageCleanupTask.java:195)
06-10 21:17:18.390 I/dalvikvm( 5973): 
06-10 21:17:18.390 W/dalvikvm( 5973): threadid=26: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f8d2a0)
06-10 21:17:18.390 E/ACRA    ( 5973): ACRA caught a OutOfMemoryError exception for com.aura.app. Building report.
```

EDIT:

Decode code is as follows:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight && width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
        // keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Pair<Integer, Bitmap> decodeSampledBitmapFromByteArray(
        byte[] data, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return new Pair<Integer, Bitmap>(options.inSampleSize,
            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using a fixed value of 1024 for `reqWidth` and `reqHeight`. If this is the case, and you're displaying the images on screen, get the width and height of the screen and use these as `reqWidth` and `reqHeight`.

By using a hardcoded value of 1024, you could be loading an image up to 2047x2047px, which would be too large for the smaller devices.

Comment: I am using a fixed value of 1024. However, I want to calculate the reqWidth and reqHeight based on available memory as the photo is posted to a server and I'd like it to have as much quality as possible. Is this even  possible?

Comment: Possible but complicated, because on older devices bitmaps were stored in native heap but on newer ones they were moved to the VM heap. You'll have to do quite a bit of research on this and it won't be reliable - free memory can change in an instant. Depending on how you're generating the image and where it's stored, streaming it to the server would be a better option because you won't need to hold it all in memory. This is a different question to what you've asked though.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the sample size. I find 2 is good enough even for large bitmap such as 12MP photo.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 2;

image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, options);
```

where filename is the filename of the bitmap.

Comment: I do set the sample size. Look at my original question, added the code that I use.